# React Native displaying text containing "<Text>" tag

Tags: react-native

I have a question with react-native

if

```
item = "foo<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bar</Text> foo"
```

How to render item WITH the style  ?

```
<Text> {item }</Text>
```

EDIT : the bold part can be any where in the item : at start, midle, end, all, none . ( i query a web service for auto complete and it return an array with highlighted part of each element )

```
 function autocomplete(search){
   // very basic example of returned data 
   return [
    "foo<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bar</Text> foo",
    "foo<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bar</Text>",
    "<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bar</Text> foo",
    "<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bar</Text>",
    "foo bar",
   ]
 }
```

EDIT 2 : it is the equivalent of `$sce.trustAsHtml(text)` with Angularjs

Comment: Can you please share the API response?

Answer (score 0):

You should write something similar to this and place that in your component class:

```
renderText(param){
  return <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{param}</Text>
}

render(){
  return (
    <View>{this.renderText("bar")}</View>
  )
}
```

Edit: You can use 3rd party module to achieve inline editing : [wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor](https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor)

Comment: thanks for help but this cannot work, i dont want to highlight all the word.  the bold part can be any where in the item, start, midle, end, all, none

Comment: did you get a solution for this? @AlainIb

Comment: @Benedict sorry i stop working on this project 2 years ago and don't remember